# Multiple sets of inputs with different and large number of samples cause memory error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a deep learning model in keras containing two sets of input data: `input1` and `input2`.

`input1` has `N` samples, and `input2` has `M` samples. The two sets of inputs would go through different layers of DNN before concatenating together. And the original output data has `M*N` samples.

What I want is that each pair of input-output would be:

```
([input1[i], input[j]], output[i,j])
```

I know that in keras `model.fit`, I have to insert `[input1, input2]` of the same sample number. However, since both of my inputs are really large, it causes memory error when I try to duplicate `input1` M times or `input2` N times in order to make their sample number equal.

I don't know if there is a way in keras or tensorflow to teach the model to fit in the sample pairs as I describe, but without the need to duplicating the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. What you would typically use for such a problem is a data generator, i.e. a generator object that creates the data during the training batch per batch, thus saving memory space.

Here is a minimal working example of a data generator based on dummy data:

```py
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# creating dummy data

M = 42
N = 123

lat_dim = 12

x_data_1 = np.random.rand(M,lat_dim)
x_data_2 = np.random.rand(N,lat_dim)

y_data   = np.random.rand(N*M)

# creating data generator

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(
        self,
        x_data_1,
        x_data_2,
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True
    ):
        'Initialization'
        self.x_data_1 = x_data_1
        self.x_data_2 = x_data_2
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle

        self.M = self.x_data_1.shape[0]
        self.N = self.x_data_2.shape[0]
        # trigger on_epoch_end() once for initialization
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(self.M * self.N / self.batch_size))

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        # create list from index to m and n
        self.index_to_m_and_n = [
            (m,n) for m in range(self.M) for n in range(self.N)
        ]

        self.index_to_m_and_n = [
            (index,mn_tuple) for index,mn_tuple in enumerate(self.index_to_m_and_n)
        ]

        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.index_to_m_and_n)

    def __getitem__(self, batch_index):
        'Generate one batch of data'

        # Generate indexes of the batch. Index can be between 0 and
        # DataGenerator.__len__ - 1
        batch_index_to_m_and_n = self.index_to_m_and_n[
            batch_index*self.batch_size:(batch_index+1)*self.batch_size
        ]

        # Generate data
        X, Y = self.__data_generation(batch_index_to_m_and_n)

        # return data
        return X, Y

    def __data_generation(self, batch_index_to_m_and_n):
        'Generates data based on batch indices'
        X1 = self.x_data_1[
            [ind_to_mn[1][0] for ind_to_mn in batch_index_to_m_and_n]
        ]

        X2 = self.x_data_2[
            [ind_to_mn[1][1] for ind_to_mn in batch_index_to_m_and_n]
        ]

        Y = np.array([
            y_data[ind_to_mn[0]]
            for ind_to_mn in batch_index_to_m_and_n
        ])

        return [X1,X2], Y

# test data generator
my_data_generator = DataGenerator(
    x_data_1,
    x_data_2,
    batch_size = 32,
    shuffle = True
)

[X1,X2],Y = my_data_generator.__getitem__(5)
print(
    'data shapes:',
    X1.shape,
    X1.shape,
    Y.shape
)
```

The output is:

```
data shapes: (32, 12) (32, 12) (32,)
```

As you can see, all the generator does is to save a list of the form `[ij,[i,j]]`. The input data of the model of the form `[x_data_1,x_data_2],y_data` is rendered for a single batch of data only when `__getitem__()` is called.

You can use data generators together with the `model.fit_generator()` method instead of `model.fit()` as you would normally do, shown here for an example model:

```py
# create simple model

x1 = keras.layers.Input(shape = lat_dim)
x2 = keras.layers.Input(shape = lat_dim)

x  = keras.layers.concatenate([x1,x2])
fx = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[x1,x2], outputs=fx)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')

print(model.summary())

model.fit_generator(
    generator = DataGenerator(
        x_data_1,
        x_data_2,
        batch_size = 32,
        shuffle = True
    )
)
```

The output is:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 12)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 12)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 24)           0           input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 1)            25          concatenate[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 25
Trainable params: 25
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/5
161/161 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2074
Epoch 2/5
161/161 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1413
Epoch 3/5
161/161 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1197
Epoch 4/5
161/161 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1071
Epoch 5/5
161/161 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0994
```

During each epoch, the `.fit_generator()` - method automatically calls `__getitem__(self, batch_index)` for `batch_index` between `0` and `__len__(self) - 1`, such that the entire dataset is used. After each epoch, `on_epoch_end(self)` is called, and the data is reshuffled.

Comment: Thank you so much! The explanations are quite clear and explicit. However, since my sample number as well as input sizes are quite large (`input1.shape = (2000000, 600, 4)`, `input2.shape=(120,1616)`, with `M=2000000`,`N=120`. I found that when using the data generator, it still encounters memory error when generating the indices of batch `batch_index_to_m_and_n` - as the list itself would also be a huge array. I wonder if their are some alternations I can make to deal with that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, you could, given the `y_data` - index (let's call it `ind`), calculate your `x1_data`-index and `x2_data` - index according to `m = int(ind/M)` and `n = ind%N`. The only thing left then is to maintain the `ind`-indices of the current batch, i.e. the re-shuffled indices of the `y_data`. There should be however a clever way to get rid of this last list as well I think. Maybe the `itertools` can do that for you

Comment: Sorry, I meant `m = int(ind/N)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked well for me without memory error!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you are happy with the answer, please click the green check mark next to it to accept it ;)